# Call function from activity to close the soft keyboard android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I'm new to mobile automation and I've been trying to find a way to close the soft keyboard on Android (using Java). The best solution I've come across so far was from this post:

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

The function that I'm trying to use from there is:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

I want to be able to call this function when the keyboard pops up, but what I don't understand is how to pass through the Activity when I call this function?

Before calling the function to close the keyboard I have the following:

```
    // Create object of  DesiredCapabilities class and specify android platform
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();


    // set the capability to execute test in android app
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Emulator_1");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "8.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.spreeza.shop.stag.debug");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.spreeza.shop.ui.features.splash.EntryPointActivity");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

// click on the login button
driver.findElement(By.id(identifierName)).click();

// close the keyboard
hideKeyboard();
```

Comment: KeyBoard Pop up when an activity is there . So just call hideKeyboard(YourActivity.this) Or simply hideKeyboard(this).

Comment: Does your keyboard pop-up when your activity opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a simple solution that works for me:

http://discuss.appium.io/t/can-we-hide-android-soft-keyboard/6956/4

I just added in these 2 capabilities:

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Activity`  => `activity` mean a reference of a Activity object.**

1. Call the method as below .

   *`hideKeyboard(YourActivity.this);`*

Checkout your `Activity` name and replace `YourActivity` with the name .

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function from Activity as `hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this)` and from Fragment as `hideKeyboard((Activity)getActivity())`

Comment: For both of those I'm getting an error saying "cannot resolve symbol getActivity" (or "MainActivity")

Comment: Replace your Activity's name in place of "MainActivity".

Comment: How do I get the Activity's name? I tried using:

    String name = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    hidekeyboard(name.this);

but that also doesn't work

Comment: Could you post the code from where you are calling this function?

Comment: Okay. That class is a Service or something?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I managed to solve the problem by adding in 2 capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Hide the keyboard
     */
    private void hideKeyboard() {
        View view = getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
                    hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```